# Error when running firebase node app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

The code (server.js) is as following following the Firebase documentation example

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://mydatabaseName.firebaseio.com",
});

var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("/Users");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

but I'm running into the error

```
Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
State changed from starting to crashed
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 22
```

After googling this issue, I tried adding to the Procfile

```
worker: node server.js

heroku ps:scale worker=1 web=0
```

None of these seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error you get after changing the Procfile? This first error happens because Heroku expects you application to bind to the Port in order to consider it initialised. But setting as a worker should have worked...

Comment: @andresk that's the error I get when setting: heroku ps:scale worker=1 web=0

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm getting exactly the same issue.

Comment: @nicholas Nope haven't figured it out. Let me know if you find a solution.